# Searching by text using xpath

Tags: javascript, xpath

I have the following markup:

```
<span id="lbl_partyType" style="color:DarkBlue;">DEFENDANT
 <span style="color:darkblue;">(<b>PRIMARY</b>)</span></span>
```

I want to target that span by the text "DEFENDANT". I want to use xpath in JavaScript to do this. I tried the following:

```
var xpath = "span[text()='DEFENDANT']";;
var matchingElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
```

matchingElement is null. What is wrong with my xpath that it is not finding the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work:

```
//span[contains(text(), 'DEFENDANT')]
```